# mariadb: table not viewable from user root

Tags: mariadb

With adminer, user root, in debian busters, a table in a mariadb database isn't read:

[image: table not shown]

Why cannot I see the table UserHistory like the others?

I suppose that the mariadb root user has all the privileges like the linux root user... or am I wrong?

Comment: Can you check what privileges are reported by `SHOW GRANTS;`?

Comment: Grants for root@localhost:
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'xxxxxxxxx' WITH GRANT OPTION

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `UserHistory` table is a view which is why the additional statistics aren't there.

Its still viewable. `SELECT * FROM UserHistroy LIMIT 10` and you'll get an answer.